# Positioning of Div in Browser with Absolute scheme

Tags: html, css

I have 2 Divs both of which are subject to `absolute position` condition. First Div has `top: 200px` and second one has `top: 400px`. However surprisingly, when I see them in Computers with different screen size, their relative positions look quite different. For example, when I see them in Laptop they appear to be closer to each other, whereas when I see then in wide-screen Desktop, they appear to be far.

I wonder, since I have `position: absolute` for both Divs, shouldn't their relative position be same regardless the screen size I chose?

What I need to do to make them appear in the same position relative to each other regardless the screen size?

**CSS details for both Divs**

```
.one {
  margin: 0 auto;
  padding: 32px 0 0 0;
  background-color: rgba(248, 248, 255, 0.15);
  height: 140px;
  position: absolute;
  top: 134px;
  width: 100%;
  text-align: center;
}

.two {
  position: absolute;
  margin: auto;
  top: 237px;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  text-align: center;
  align-items: center;
}
```

Thanks for your advice.

Comment: What do you have set for their height?

Comment: Hi  SirExotic, I have modified my original post with CSS details.

Comment: don't do this. when mobile users click on an input, the virtual keyboard pops up and over fixed (and I'm pretty sure absolute) positioned elements. Use a simple flexbox or even grid layout

Comment: What I observed basically is, when I reduce Browser size vertically, the 2nd Div is moving upwards thereby reducing the 'gap' between Div 1 and 2, ultimately Div-2 is covering Div-1.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that you're using `bottom: 0` for the second div, instead of a **height**. This means that the bottom of your second div will always be at the bottom of the page, so if you resize it, this div will become taller proportionally to the height of your screen size.

To fix this, I removed the `top`, `left` and `right` positioning and instead applied a `height` (like in your first div) and a `width` of 100%.

```css
.one {
  position: absolute;
  margin: 0 auto;
  padding: 32px 0 0 0;
  background-color: pink;
  height: 140px;
  top: 134px;
  width: 100%;
  text-align: center;
}

.two {
  height: 100px;
  width: 100%;
  position: absolute;
  margin: auto;
  background-color: steelblue;
  top: 237px;
  text-align: center;
  align-items: center;
}
```

```html
<div class="one"></div>

<div class="two"></div>
```

Answer (score 1):

In other to make look same regardless of screen size, you have to set the properties say `left=0` , `right=0` and `bottom=0`for bottom div and then you could control the height using different `top`  values. Doing this you have make both div behave like a block container with absolute position and their placement will not shift each other like relative.

```
        .one {
      margin: 0 auto;
      padding: 32px 0 0 0;
      background-color: red;
      height: 140px;
      position: absolute;
      top: 134px;
      left: 0;
      right: 0;
      bottom:0;
      width: 100%;
      text-align: center;
      border: 1px solid blue;
    }

    .two {
      position: absolute;
      margin: auto;
      top: 237px;
      bottom: 0;
      left: 0;
      right: 0;
      text-align: center;
      align-items: center;
      background-color: green;
      border: 1px solid blue;
    }

        <div class="one">
        1
        </div>
        <div class="two">
        2
        </div>
```

Answer (score 1):

This can be one solution.

```css
*{box-sizing:border-box;}

.one {
  position: absolute;
  margin: 0 auto;
  padding: 32px 0 0 0;
  background-color: pink;
  height: 140px;
  top: 134px;
  width: 100%;
  text-align: center;
}

.two {
  height: 140px;
  width: 100%;
  position: absolute;
  margin: auto;
  background-color: steelblue;
  top: 274px;
  text-align: center;
  align-items: center;
}
```

```html
<div class="one"></div>
<div class="two"></div>
```

The other solution is to just group them into 1 div, make make that div absolute.

The advantage of this is that u dont have to maintain positioning of 2 divs. Only the parent is enough

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.parent {
  position: absolute;
  top: 134px;
  width:100%;
  left:0;
  right:0;
}

.one {
  margin: 0 auto;
  padding: 32px 0 0 0;
  background-color: pink;
  height: 140px;
  width: 100%;
  text-align: center;
}

.two {
  height: 140px;
  width: 100%;
  margin: auto;
  background-color: steelblue;
  text-align: center;
  align-items: center;
}
```

```html
<div class="parent">
  <div class="one"></div>
  <div class="two"></div>
</div>
```